# Global search with RESTful API in ruby and json requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, restful-url, rails-api

I am working on implementing a search endpoint with ruby based on a json request sent from the client which should have the form
GET /workspace/:id/searches? filter[query]=Old&filter[type]=ct:Tag,User,WokringArea&items=5
So far I added the searches controller but I'm not sure how to extract the params in that json request to ruby syntax

```
class SearchesController < ApiV3Controller
    load_and_authorize_resource :workspace, class: "Company"
    load_and_authorize_resource :user, through: :workspace
    load_and_authorize_resource :working_area, through: :workspace

    def index
    end

    private

    def ability_klasses
      [WorkspaceAbility, UserWorkspaceAbility, WorkingAreaAbility]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class SearchesController < ApiV3Controller

    load_and_authorize_resource :workspace, class: "Company"
    load_and_authorize_resource :user, through: :workspace
    load_and_authorize_resource :working_area, through: :workspace

    def index
      puts("filtered_params:", filtered_params)
      puts("Query parameter:" filtered_params[:query])
      puts("Type parameter:" filtered_params[:type])
      #Based on condition invoke the appropriate model
      if filtered_params[:type] == 'WorkspaceAbility'
        #search query
      end
    end

    private

    def filtered_params
      params.require(:filter).permit(:query, :type, :items)
    end
  end
```